# Create multiple identical columns with different names within a dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create multiple identical columns with different names within a dataframe using Pandas.

**Data**

```
ID  type    name    series  date                            
AA  all     sue     111     1/1/2023                            
AA  ok      devon   222     1/1/2023                            
BB  yes     carey   333     1/1/2023                            
CC  maybe   carey   444     1/1/2023
```

**Desired**

```
ID  type    type1   type2   type3   name    name1   name2   name3   series  series1 date
AA  all     all     all     all     sue     sue     sue     sue     111     111     1/1/2023
AA  ok      ok      ok      ok      devon   devon   devon   devon   222     222     1/1/2023
BB  yes     yes     yes     yes     carey   carey   carey   carey   333     333     1/1/2023
CC  maybe   maybe   maybe   maybe   carey   carey   carey   carey   444     444     1/1/2023
```

**Doing**

```
# Define the number of times to duplicate the column
n_duplicates = 3

# Duplicate a specific column n times using assign and concat
duplicates = [df['column_name']] * n_duplicates
new_columns = pd.concat(duplicates, axis=1)

# Add the duplicated columns to the DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df, new_columns], axis=1)
```

However this is not producing my desired outcome.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You show only 2 repeats for "series", is this a mistake?

Comment: no the series column needs only 2 duplicates @mozway

Comment: OK, then use the first part of my answer with `cols = df.columns.repeat([1, 4, 4, 2, 1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
cols = df.columns.repeat([1, 4, 4, 4, 1])

out = df.loc[:, cols]

s = cols.to_series().groupby(cols).cumcount()
out.columns += np.where(s>0, '_'+s.astype(str), '')
```

If you want to make the column creation dynamic:

```
to_duplicate = ['type', 'name', 'series']
n = 3
cols = df.columns.repeat(df.columns.isin(to_duplicate)+n)

# rest of the previous code
out = df.loc[:, cols]
s = cols.to_series().groupby(cols).cumcount()
out.columns += np.where(s>0, '_'+s.astype(str), '')
```

Output:

```
   ID   type type_1 type_2 type_3   name name_1 name_2 name_3  series  \
0  AA    all    all    all    all    sue    sue    sue    sue     111   
1  AA     ok     ok     ok     ok  devon  devon  devon  devon     222   
2  BB    yes    yes    yes    yes  carey  carey  carey  carey     333   
3  CC  maybe  maybe  maybe  maybe  carey  carey  carey  carey     444   

   series_1  series_2  series_3      date  
0       111       111       111  1/1/2023  
1       222       222       222  1/1/2023  
2       333       333       333  1/1/2023  
3       444       444       444  1/1/2023
```

Comment: wondering if this is used to specify the number of duplicates for a specific column? cols = df.columns.repeat([1, 4, 4, 4, 1])

Comment: Yes, if you want only 2 cols for `series`: `cols = df.columns.repeat([1, 4, 4, 2, 1])`

Comment: Ok will try this solution in a few - thank you for the suggestion @mozway

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df_columns = pd.concat([df] * n, axis=1)
```

And to rename the column names so that they are unique:

```
def uniquify(df_columns):
    seen = set()

    for item in df_columns:
        fudge = 1
        newitem = item

        while newitem in seen:
            fudge += 1
            newitem = "{}_{}".format(item, fudge)

        yield newitem
        seen.add(newitem)

df_columns.columns=list(uniquify(df_columns))
```